# node-mssql - Connection is closed

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure

I use node typescript with `mssql` library to insert data into tables in my Azure server. I create a global connection pool, init it in the constructor then connect to it from route service. However, it shows the error

> ConnectionError: Connection is closed at ActionService.insertion", "...at new ActionService", "... at new AppDataServices".

I don't know where broke down my logical connection between the global pool and route service. My SQL query might be wrong, but the main thing is about connection to the database.

Below is my code:

app-data-services.ts (global connection pool):

```
import * as mssql from 'mssql';
import { AppConfig } from '../config';
import { ActionService } from './data-services';
import { Logger, LoggerFactory } from '../common';

export class AppDataServices {
  private static readonly LOGGER: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger();

  private db: any;

  public actionService: ActionService;

  constructor(private appConfig: AppConfig) {
    this.initConnectionPool();
    this.actionService = new ActionService(this.db, AppDataServices.LOGGER);
  }

  private initConnectionPool() {
    this.db = new mssql.ConnectionPool({
      user: this.appConfig.mssqlUsername,
      password: this.appConfig.mssqlPassword,
      server: this.appConfig.mssqlServer,
      database: this.appConfig.mssqlDatabase,
      // If you are on Microsoft Azure, you need this:
      options: { encrypt: true }
    }, (err: any) => {
      if (err) AppDataServices.LOGGER.error('MSSQL error', err);
    });
  }    
}
```

action-service.ts (route data service):

```
import * as mssql from 'mssql';
import { Logger, LoggerFactory } from '../../../common';

export class ActionService {
  private static readonly LOGGER: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger();

  constructor (private db: any, private logger: any) {
    this.insertion();
  }

  insertion() {
    const request = new mssql.Request(this.db);
    request.query(
      `
        INSERT INTO dbo.action
          (timestamp, result, description, request_endpoint, request_payload, response_status, response_payload, actualAmount, rule_id, lendbook_id)
        SELECT t1.start, 'SUCCESS', NULL, '/lendbook/usd', NULL, '200', NULL, t1.originalAmount, t1.id, t2.id
        FROM dbo.rule t1, dbo.lendbook t2
        INNER JOIN t2.id = t1.id
      `, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }
        return result.recordsets[0];
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try by adding connecting to the pool (use something like `this.db.connect(function(err, result) {if (result) {rest of your code here}}`) as the first line in your `insertion` method?

Comment: then it returns this error: "{ ConnectionError: Already connecting to database! Call close before connecting to different database."